# Поиск строки в подстроке PHP

Tags: php

Есть вот такой код:
    $ara['qwe'] = "рольставни купить";
    $search = "оль";
    $pos = strpos($ara['qwe'], $search);
    if ($pos == true) { echo "+"; }

Если переменная search равна "оль", то выводится +, а если "роль", но ничего не выводится. Вопрос, почему первый символ функцией strpos не учитывается? Благодарю!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

strpos возвращает целое число или false. [Природа PHP такова](http://habrahabr.ru/post/142140/), что существуют два типа сравнения: строгое и нестрогое, и их можно описать так: строгое - "А совпадает с Б", нестрогое - "А похоже на Б". Вы используете нестрогое (строгим было бы ===, три символа в операторе), и в процессе этого сравнения $pos приводится к булевому значению - а для нуля это false (для 1 и более это был бы true). Об этом, кстати, есть даже [специальный блок](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strpos.php#refsect1-function.strpos-returnvalues) на странице документации (лучше бы вообще к чертям выкинули нестрогое сравнение, блин).

Чтобы быть уверенным в результате, надо использовать строгое сравнение:

```
if ($pos !== false) { // вуаля, ноль не пройдет
```

P.S. if ($pos == true) абсолютно идентично if ($pos). Когда вам нужно привести к булевому типу (NB: это работает, как нестрогое сравнение), не сравнивайте с булевым типом.

Comment: отличный ответ, проблема решена! благодарю вас! :)